# How to know that whether particular user is signed in to the stackoverflow or not right now?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, users

I had asked one question and got great answers,from that one answer I had accepted. Now I have follow-up question with that answer and I am also sending the message using @ character and username with it but I want to that particular user  is online or not means  right now is he/she signed in to the stackoverflow or not ?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20299/is-stalking-anti-stalking-bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is a "seen" field on the user profile which is public -- this will tell you the last time our website saw them with a granularity of about 15 minutes.

Comment: @jeff atwood sir, about 15 minutes means he is sign out before that time ?

Comment: @Harikrishna: No, that means the displayed time was the last time the user requested a page, plus or minus a couple of minutes. I think most people don't even sign out. But even if they went to bed, they'll receive the message that you adressed them in a comment as soon as they come back to the site.